# How to connect G-WAN to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, g-wan

I have a web server running G-WAN and CentOS. I'm trying to figure out the best way to make a connection to a Microsoft SQL Sever database. The most I need to do at this point is a simple insert from a G-WAN handler, nothing fancy.

Anyone have any experience with this?

My language preference is C#, Though C++ or C is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with MS-SQL server but I guess that you have to use a 'connector' (probably an OBDC client library).

Several Linux libraries exist for that purpose.

Other than that, here are a couple of recommendations:

1) C# is available in G-WAN v3.9+

2) if your C# code works without G-WAN then it will also work when executed from G-WAN.

Comment: Can you give a release date for these version ? Plus, I can't find the g-wan twitter account...

Comment: This month. The http://gwan.com Web site is the reference for news but the Twitter account is: G-WAN @TrustLeap_GWAN

Answer (score 0):

I saw the libsdb C library http://siag.nu/libsdb/ (but not tried).

Supported databases:

Gdbm,
Ingres,
Lago,
**Microsoft SQL**,
Mimer,
MiniSQL,
Mysql,
Sqlite versions 2 and 3,
Postgresql,
Oracle,
Shsql/quisp,
Sybase,
Text (built-in plaintext engine)